# Reading text file into string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file, getline

I'm trying to read the contents of a file object into an array of strings, but whatever I try nothing is displayed when I print the contents of the array. Specifically, I want to print the last ten lines of the text file by passing them into the array, and using a for loop on the array.

```
void FileReader::displayLast10records(){

    ifstream ifile(filename);
    string myArray[26];

    cout << "\n" << filename << ":  LAST 10 records in file \n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < numrecords; i++)
        getline(ifile, myArray[i]);

    ifile.close();

    if (numrecords < 10)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numrecords; i++)
            cout << setw(2) << (i + 1) << ".\t" << myArray[i] << endl;
    }
    else if (numrecords > 10)
    {
        for (int i = (numrecords - 10); i < numrecords; i++)
        {
            cout << setw(2) << (i + 1) << ".\t" << myArray[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The file(s) are simply large blocks of text, including spaces. The file looks like:

> A programming language is an artificial language designed
>   to communicate instructions to a machine, particularly
>   a computer. Programming languages can be used to create
>   programs that control the behavior of a machine and/or to
>   express algorithms precisely.
>   The earliest programming languages predate the invention
>   of the computer, and were used to direct the behavior of
>   machines such as Jacquard looms and player pianos.
>   Thousands of different programming languages have been
>   created, mainly in the computer field, with many being
>   created every year. Most programming languages describe
>   computation in an imperative style, i.e., as a sequence
>   of commands, although some languages, such as those that
>   support functional programming or logic programming, use
>   alternative forms of description.

I want to read each line into it's own element of a string array.

I do have another function that successfully uses getline() to display each line of the text file 10 lines at a time.

```
void FileReader::displayAllRecords(){

ifstream ifile(filename);
int displayed_lines = 0;
string arec;

cout <<"\n" << filename << ": ALL records in the file with line numbers, 10 at a time \n\n";

while (getline(ifile, arec))
{
    if(displayed_lines % 10 == 0 && displayed_lines >= 1)
        system("pause");

    cout << setw(2) << (displayed_lines + 1) << ".\t" << arec << endl;
    displayed_lines++;
}


ifile.close();
}
```

Comment: In which format you're storing data in file?

Comment: Oh, right. Each line of the file(s) are lines of text including spaces. Something like: A programming language is an artificial language designed
to communicate instructions to a machine, particularly
a computer. Programming languages can be used to create
programs that control the behavior of a machine and/or to
express algorithms precisely.

Comment: I don't think the following is the error but you open the file twice. First using the constructor ifstream ifile(filename); and secondly using the function ifile.open(filename);.

Comment: Ok. Thank you, I'll fix that.

Comment: seems like an ideal scenario for firing up the debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is how you could read lines using [ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

void readFile(const char* filename, list<string>& lines)
{
    lines.clear();
    ifstream file(filename);
    string s;
    while (getline(file, s))
        lines.push_back(s);
}
```

or to read last 10 lines:

```
void readLast10(const char* filename, list<string>& lines)
{
    lines.clear();
    ifstream file(filename);
    string s;
    while (getline(file, s))
    {
        lines.push_back(s);
        if (line.size() > 10)
            lines.pop_front();
    }
}
```

and then you can print last 10 lines:

```
int main()
{
    list<string> lines;
    readFile(filename, lines);
    int n = 0;
    printf("read %d lines\n", lines.size());
    for (auto const it=lines.rbegin(); it!=lines.rend() && n<10; ++it, ++n)
        printf("line%2u:\t%s\n", lines.size()-n, it->c_str());
}
```

or like that:

```
int main()
{
    list<string> lines;
    readLast10(filename, lines);
    int n = 0;
    cout << "read " << lines.size() << endl;
    for (const auto& line : lines)
        cout << l << endl;
}
```

Note that [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) reads line by line, that is, if your text doesn't contain line breaks your entire file will be read as if it was only one file.

Comment: Alright, thank you for that. So, without line breaks in the file itself, I can't just read each line into a regular array?

Comment: @johnbodhi Without line breaks you do not have lines, but only one very long line.

Comment: I see. I do have another function here that successfully displays each line 10 lines at a time using getline though. I don't know how to display it in these comments.

Comment: You can edit your original question and add it there.

Comment: Not sure what I did, but it is working now! Haha. I will learn more about lists for the future per everyone's advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your file doesn't contain proper line end markers like your program expects but your code *assumes* that file just got `numrecords` end-of-line markers. Where that variable defined and how you get it  is other question.
Do not use static array here, use std::list,  use `list::reverse_iterator` (can get value from `list::rbegin()`, iterate 10 times unless iterator becomes equal to  list::rend()) to iterate through last 10 records, your code would be far simpler (actually, just few lines)

Comment: Thanks. I'm not very familiar with lists yet, but I'll see what I can do. The numrecords is a private member variable that is defined once each line of the file has been read in another member function.